# Bind collections from TabItems to a single DataGrid when selected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, tabcontrol

I have a Window with a TabControl containing two TabItems, each containing a UserControl. These's viewmodels inherit from a BaseViewModel containing an ObservableCollection property.

Under the TabControl, I have a DataGrid; the Window's viewmodel contains the same ObservableCollection property as the BaseViewModel, and the DataGridView binds to it.

How can I bind the selected viewmodel's collection to the DataGrid, directly or not (eg. MyWindow.MyCollection = selectedVM.MyCollection)?

The idea is to update the DataGrid to always show the content of the selected tab's collection.

Comment: sounds like a design flaw somewhere please explain in a better what what your problem is exactly ?

Comment: Show some code and the structure of your prrogram explicityly